# Changing the attributes of each element of an object array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, physics

I have some conceptual doubts, sorry if they're simple but I'm stuck.

In a simulation of the formation of a galaxy I have a class called `SolarSystem`.

```
class SolarSystem
{
private:
    double sPositionX, sVelocityX, sPositionY;
    double  sVelocityY, sMass, sExcentricity;
public:
//Methods like getPosition(), etc
}
```

In my main function I have the object array `SolarSystem systems[1000]`. I need to implement an algorithm to make the solar systems move in my galaxy (following the laws of Newton) and thus, I have to change the values of the attributes of each member of the array like position, velocity, etc. (N-Body problem).

- I suposse that I can't make a **method** `algorithm()` that changes the values, because there is a dependence of the systems with each other, and the method can't take into account other members of the array.
- However, if I chose to change the attributes in a **function**, I
  would need those to be public, and then, is there a reason to make a
  class? Wouldn't it be easier to have the attributes as variables `positionX[i], mass[i], etc` in my main function `int main()`?

Comment: There is an advantage to have the values for one star system together. You can also define a struct (a struct is very similar to a class in C++). Alternatively you could make your member variables public and access them from member functions (methods). There is also the concept of friend functions that can access private member variables. It also depends on your algorithm. I would say there there are several right ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create an other class called "Galaxy" for example, that contains your systems.

```
#include <vector>
#include <SolarSystem.h>
Galaxy {
   std::vector<SolarSystem> system;
public :
   //construtor and destructor
   void algorithm();
   //some other methods like this :
   void addSolarSystem(SolarSystem& system);
};
```

Finally, in ***algorithm*** you can modify your systems with getters and setters from the SolarSystem class (or methods : ***accelerate(float value)***, ...).

It's better to create an other class because it's reality : galaxy contains solar systems and this container (galaxy) links your dependencies. More, you should always apply the "Single-responsibility principle" [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) : Your solar system cannot influence on other system but only on planets into this system (single responsibility). Without this principle you will have some problems when you will implement other things (comets...).

Usually, it's better to encapsulate your data and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Classes allow you to structure your data in meaningfull way, improving extensibility, maintainability and making your code easier to understand. If your main problem is to access `systems` from a class, you could just pass it as parameter. In modern C++ you should use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of C-style-arrays. For example:

```
class SolarSystem
{
private:
    double sPositionX, sVelocityX, sPositionY;
    double  sVelocityY, sMass, sExcentricity;
public:
    // getters and setters and stuff

    void algorithm(const std::vector<SolarSystem> &otherSystems) {
        for(const auto &otherSystem : otherSystems) {
            // iterate through all systems...
        }
    }
}
```

If you store your solar systems also in a `std::vector` like

```
std::vector<SolarSystem> solarSystems;
```

You could iterate throught it and update all the systems like this:

```
for(auto &system : solarSystems) {
    system.algorithm(solarSystems);
}
```